# Can I disable window autoplay function programatically with C#/.NET?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, autoplay

Does anybody know a way to deactivate the autoplay function of windows using c#/.NET?

Comment: Throught the Windows API, and likely P/Invoke. Additionally, look into this registry key -- http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc959381.aspx

Comment: See - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/280787/suppress-autoplay

Comment: @Nate If you want to disable Autoplay for the whole computer rather than just one user, use the same registry key in that link except under HKLM rather than HKCU

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A little summary, for all the others looking for a good way to disable/supress autoplay.
So far I've found 3 methods to disable autoplay programatically:

1. Intercepting the [QueryCancelAutoPlay message](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/PreventCDAutoPlayPackage.aspx)
2. Using the [Registry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc144204%28VS.85%29.aspx#nodrive)
3. Implementing the COM Interface [IQueryCancelAutoPlay](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb761373%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)

In the end I chose the 3rd method and used the IQueryCancelAutoPlay interface because the others had some signifcant disadvantages:

- The first method
  (QueryCancelAutoPlay) was only able
  to suppress autoplay if the
  application window was in the foreground, cause [only the foreground window receives the message](http://www.codeproject.com/Messages/2313454/Important-point-missing.aspx)
- Configuring autoplay in the registry worked even if the application window was in the background. The downside: It required a restart of the currently running *explorer.exe* to take effect...so this was no solution to temporarily disable autoplay.

---

### Examples for the implementation

**1. QueryCancelAutoPlay**

- [Suppressing AutoRun Programmatically](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc144204%28VS.85%29.aspx#suppressing) (MSDN article)
- [CodeProject: Preventing a CD from Auto-Playing](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/PreventCDAutoPlayPackage.aspx)
- [Canceling AutoPlay from C#](http://www.brianensink.com/blog/post/Canceling-AutoPlay-from-C.aspx)

*Note: If your application is using a dialog box you need to call [SetWindowLong](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633591.aspx) ([signature](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/SetWindowLongPtr.html)) instead of just returning false. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc144204%28VS.85%29.aspx#suppressing) for more details)*

**2. Registry**

Using the registry you can disables AutoRun for specified drive letters (NoDriveAutoRun) or for a class of drives ([NoDriveTypeAutoRun](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/280787/suppress-autoplay/280813#280813))

- [Using the Registry to Disable AutoRun](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc144204%28VS.85%29.aspx#nodrive) (MSDN article)
- [How to Enable / Disable Autorun for a Drive (using Registry)](http://www.samlogic.net/articles/autorun-enable-disable-nodrivetypeautorun.htm)
- [Windows 7 AutoPlay Enable | Disable](http://www.computerperformance.co.uk/windows7/windows7_autoplay.htm)

**3. IQueryCancelAutoPlay**

- [Reference for the IQueryCancelAutoPlay](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb761373%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) interface on MSDN
- [IQueryCancelAutoPlay only called once?](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-IE/windowssdk/thread/aef929cb-62ac-4371-b7de-2c07adf3c6a7) (Example implementatio, also read comments)
- [AutoPlayController](http://convert.codes-sources.com/file2cs.aspx?ID=47727&f=AutorunLib/AutoplayControler.vb) (another implementation, not tested)

### Some other links:

- [Enabling and Disabling AutoRun](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc144204%28VS.85%29.aspx#nodrive) (MSDN article)
- [Autoplay in Windows XP: Automatically Detect and React to New Devices on a System](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc301341.aspx) (an old but extensive article on Autoplay)

Answer (score 1):

> RegisterWindowMessage is a Win32 API call. So you will need to use PInvoke to make it work..

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

class Win32Call
{
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
   public static extern int RegisterWindowMessage(String strMessage);
}

// In your application you will call

Win32Call.RegisterWindowMessage("QueryCancelAutoPlay");
```

[From here](http://www.google.co.za/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=Disable+autoplay+using+C%23) (The Experts-Exchange link at the top). There is additional help on that site with some more examples that may be a little more comprehensive than the above. The above does however solve the problem.

Comment: @Kyle - you can't see the content from e-e via a direct link, unless you join. The content only shows up when you link from a Google search.

Comment: @ChrisF - That I did not know, thanks, I've updated the link to a google link of the site.

Comment: You can't scroll to the bottom of the page anymore? E-E used to work that way when you didn't have a login. But at least there's Google Cache...

Comment: Very important: This event is only sent to the current foreground window!
http://www.codeproject.com/Messages/2313454/Important-point-missing.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Some additional links that might be helpful:

- [Preventing a CD from
  Auto-Playing](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/PreventCDAutoPlayPackage.aspx) shows some example
  vb.net code, showing the usage of
  "QueryCancelAutoPlay" on CodeProject.
- [Enabling and Disabling AutoRun](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc144204%28VS.85%29.aspx) on MSDN.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code work for me :) For more info check out this reference link : http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.registerwindowmessage

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

//provide a private internal message id
private UInt32 queryCancelAutoPlay = 0;

[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError=true, CharSet=CharSet.Auto)]
static extern uint RegisterWindowMessage(string lpString);

/* only needed if your application is using a dialog box and needs to 
* respond to a "QueryCancelAutoPlay" message, it cannot simply return TRUE or FALSE.
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern int SetWindowLong(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex, int dwNewLong);
*/

protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
{
    //calling the base first is important, otherwise the values you set later will be lost
    base.WndProc (ref m);

    //if the QueryCancelAutoPlay message id has not been registered...
    if (queryCancelAutoPlay == 0)
        queryCancelAutoPlay = RegisterWindowMessage("QueryCancelAutoPlay");

    //if the window message id equals the QueryCancelAutoPlay message id
    if ((UInt32)m.Msg == queryCancelAutoPlay)
    {
        /* only needed if your application is using a dialog box and needs to
        * respond to a "QueryCancelAutoPlay" message, it cannot simply return TRUE or FALSE.
        SetWindowLong(this.Handle, 0, 1);
        */
        m.Result = (IntPtr)1;
    }
} //WndProc
```