# IQueryCancelAutoPlay WPF implementation

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010, windows-7

Which reference should I add to my WPF application so I can implement IQueryCancelAutoPlay interface ?

Here is code example that produces error
 *The type or namespace name 'IQueryCancelAutoPlay' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)*

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace DisableAutorun {
    [ComVisible(true)]
    [Guid("63DA3B72-E9C9-4d40-B7DA-DC537C4C5CC2")]
    [ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
    public class Autoplay : IQueryCancelAutoPlay, IDisposable {
        private RunningObjectTableEntry rotEntry;

        public Autoplay() {
            rotEntry = new RunningObjectTableEntry(this);
        }

        public int AllowAutoPlay(string pszPath, Content dwContentType, string pszLabel, int dwSerialNumber) {


            Console.WriteLine("QueryCancelAutoPlay:");
            Console.WriteLine("   " + pszPath);
            Console.WriteLine("   " + dwContentType.ToString("x"));
            Console.WriteLine("   " + pszLabel);
            Console.WriteLine("   " + dwSerialNumber.ToString());

            return 1;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Exact duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2732792/can-i-disable-window-autoplay-function-programatically-with-c-net

Comment: I already tried to use code referenced there from http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-IE/windowssdk/thread/aef929cb-62ac-4371-b7de-2c07adf3c6a7, but I'm getting compiler error, that's why I'm asking this question

Comment: Please, post your code and error message.