# C# web app to suppress AutoPlay window (from USB detection)

Tags: c#, web-applications, com

I've seen a few different posts on using Win32 to intercept when the AutoRun window is attempting to launch and suppressing it.  Unfortunately, those posts I've seen have only been in c++ and winforms.  Is there a way to accomplish this in a web application using C# codebehind (non-winform / non-console / no registry key editing)?

I was looking at this post as a reference:
[Can I disable window autoplay function programatically with C#/.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2732792/can-i-disable-window-autoplay-function-programatically-with-c-net)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You want the web-site to disable the user's autoplay feature?

Comment: Please clarify... Are you trying to disable autoplay on the *server* on which the web app is running, or on the *client* which is accessing the web app?  The former should work exactly the same as any other C# approach, the latter is not possible for obvious reasons.

Comment: I'm using WMI to detect when USB removable devices are added, but I'd like to suppress the AutoRun window when they are.  I'm only doing this on a specific page and not globally to simplify and not override the AutoRun everytime

Comment: I was basically trying to figure out if using P/Invoke to call Win32 was possible (kinda like Silverlight OOB type apps) that can intercept.  Maybe tis not possible though and I'll have to deal with the window or maybe find a way to keep the application window in the front and the AutoRun window in the back (if possible)